# Question on Sets with string & numeric elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I was trying to solve following,

> $A = \{n ∈ N : 1≤ n^2 ≤10\}$ and $B = \{ab, c\}$.
>   (a) $A∪B =$
>   (b) $A×B =$

My answers for them:
(a) $\{1,4,9,ab,c\}$
(b) $\{(1,ab), (1,c), (4,ab),\dotsc, (9,ab), (9,c)\}$

I am very much unsure of $B=\{ab,d\}...$
I know it is easy if it was just $B=\{a,d\}$ but two characters $ab$ in one element makes me kinda confused.

Are my answers correct?

Comment: You are absolutely right.  Don't worry about the number of characters.  It, the two character string, is still just an element of B  And an ordered pair is just an ordered pair no matter what the actual elements are.

Comment: Your elements of A are incorrect, but very close.  A is supposed to contain the $n$'s not the $n^2$'s.

Comment: (a)={1,2,3,ab,c}